# .net core 3.0/3.1 write custom response to http request

Tags: .net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.1

I'm writing an Api gateway and implementing the custom aggregators that we need. To do this I am taking the any incoming http request via the middleware, interrogating the request to see if this is one I need to handle and, if so, making multiple downstream calls to different apis to get the fragments I need to re-assemble back together to make the response. If it's not one I want to handle, I just forward it to the downstream system (e.g. like a reverse proxy), so I'm not implementing web api controllers just middleware interception.

In .net core 2.x I'd use something like originalIncomingRequest.CreateResponse to create my custom response after all the aggregated calls have finished and then write to the response body my stitched together json response.

This extension method doesn't appear to exist in .net core 3.x

it looks like I'm stuck with this (e.g.)

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aggregation);
var b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

originalIncomingRequest.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;
await request.HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(b, 0, b.Length);
```

but this is a pattern from a very long time ago.... is there something simpler in .net core 3.x to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this code as a middleware you should try some code like this:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(<aggregation>);
    var b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(b, 0, b.Length);
});
```